# Open App Settings tapping a Codename One Button

Tags: codenameone

Is there any code that I can insert in the `ActionListener` of a Codename One `Button` to open the app settings on iPhone and on Android?

I saw something similar in other apps, for example to help the user to manually change the app permissions. In my case, I'd like to easily open the app settings to inspect the amount of total storage taken by the app (as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53992872/2670744) and other infos provided by Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but `execute("app-settings:")` (from `Display` or `CN`) might work. If not you will need to use native code, specifically:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

As mentioned here: [How to open settings from my iPad application (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558836/how-to-open-settings-from-my-ipad-application-objective-c/25558855)

Comment: Thank you. For completeness: `execute("app-settings:")` works on iOS only. On Android, I needed to create a native interface, that I shared here: https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/3397f1cf7853532ddc9c56a09aae8b3b

Comment: Sorry I missed the point where you asked about Android. I'm pretty sure there is an execute string we can use to launch that too

Comment: I tried to search the String "app-settings" in the Codename One sources, but I didn't find it. So that feature is not implemented by Codename One, but is it implemented by the operating system (iOS in this case)? I'm interested in a list of these Strings because if they exist then they can be useful, however I didn't find documentation.

Comment: Just google iphone url schemes. This is the current top result: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/ I wrote about this a while back and back then there was a different top result. You can also expose your own app using a similar URL scheme of your own